# Efficient way of checking multiple function arguments for NULL in C

Tags: c, function, null, parameter-passing, return-value

I am just wondering is there a more efficient way to check if any argument passed to a function contains a NULL pointer?
So far this is what I have been using as an argument check. I want the function to return -1 if any input is NULL.

```
int Func(const char *one, const char *two){

    if( !one || !two ){
        return -1;
    }

    //rest of the function code
}
```

This is fine for a function that accepts two arguments; however, it looks messy if I have a function that receives three or more arguments. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Just do it. I have worked in ultra-high-performance code where we needed to optimize tests like this, and some optimization be done by relying on certain properties of the specific C implementation and bitwise ORing the pointers together so that only a single test-and-branch is necessary. But it is just not worth it outside of exceptional circumstances. Write the tests out in the normal way and let the compiler do its thing.

Comment: “Looks fine”. Could apply the inverse: `if(!(a && b && ..)) return -1;`, if that suits your fancy more. There might be some argument to be made for using `|` or `&` respectively, although I’d stick to the logical operators as it (realistically) won’t make a difference.. and depends on compiler and input.

Comment: @user2864740 Bitwise operators are problematic.  You'd have to cast the pointers to integers to use them.  And even as integers, `&` would fail to handle cases where two non-null pointers have no bits in common.

Comment: Ah, true. Brain oops there on the `&`. I’d stick to the logical operators.

Comment: PS I thought to myself. Do you really need the inverse operator? How about: `if (a && b && nth) {/* your code */} else {return -1;}`

Comment: PS place the most profound parameter to the left. For example, when in 80% of all NULL-pointer cases parameter `b` is accountable for, place parameter `b` to the most left within your `if()` statement, like: `if(b && a && nth)`, so the logical `&&` chain aborts as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your macros for that. For example for 5 parameters:

```
#define EVAL(a, ...)!(a) || EVAL1(__VA_ARGS__)
#define EVAL1(a, ...)!(a) || EVAL2(__VA_ARGS__)
#define EVAL2(a, ...)!(a) || EVAL3(__VA_ARGS__)
#define EVAL3(a, ...)!(a) || EVAL4(__VA_ARGS__)
#define EVAL4(a, ...)!(a) 

#define MYASSERT5(...) EVAL(__VA_ARGS__)

int myfunc(const char *p1, const char *p2, const char *p3, const char *p4, const char *p5)
{
    if(MYASSERT5(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5)) return -1;
}
```

Comment: And the nice thing about macros is you can use them to embed debug calls that emit the function name, file, and line number.  **When** a bug appears, the easiest way to find out what a program is doing wrong is to have it tell you in a log.